# to get output from variable

Tags: perl, perl-module

```
 use strict;
 use warnings;

 $manifest=read_file("release.ms1");
 print "$manifest\n";

 my @new=split('\.',$manifest);

 my %data=@new;

 print "$data('vcs version')";
```

content of the release.ms1

```
vcs.version:12312321
vcs.path:CiscoMain/IT/GIS/trunk
```

Error:

vcs.version:12312321

vcs.path:CiscoMain/IT/GIS/trunk

vcsversion:12312321

vcspath:CiscoMain/IT/GIS/trunk

Odd number of elements in hash assignment at ./script.pl line 33.

Use of uninitialized value in print at ./script.pl line 35.

I need output like :

```
version=12312321
path=CiscoMain/IT/GIS/trunk
```

Comment: You give an error that references line 27, yet you provide only 11 lines of code. `read_file` is nowhere defined. And you need `my` in front of `$manifest`.

Comment: Looks to me like line 27 is `my %data = @new;` and 29 is the `print` line.

Comment: Hi Barmar, actually i have skipped the unwanted lines here

Comment: Then you should make it easy on readers and point out which lines the error messages refer to.

Answer (score 1):

Your `split` function is assigning:

```
$new[0] = 'vcs'
$new[1] = 'version:12312321\nvcs'
$new[2] = 'path:CiscoMain/IT/GIS/trunk'
```

When you assign a list to a hash, it has to have an even number of elements, since they're required to be alternating keys and values.

It looks like what you actually want to do is split `$manifest` on newlines and colons, and replace the dots in the keys with space.

```
my @new = split(/[.\n]/, @manifest;
my %data;
for (my $i = 0; $i < @new; $i += 2) {
    my $key = $new[$i];
    $key =~ s/\./ /g;
    $data{$key} = $new[$i+1];
}
```

Finally, your syntax for accessing an element of the hash is wrong. It should be:

```
print $data{'vcs version'};
```

The hash key is surrounded with curly braces, not parentheses.

Comment: Hi Barmar, split is working fine . But hashes function isn't getting

Comment: Sorry, too much PHP lately, I wrote the assignment wrong.